# Python unittest error when launching it from command line

Tags: python, command-line, python-unittest

I have such app organization:

```
Project /
    application /
        __init__.py
        *some stuff*
        settings.py
    tests /
        __init__.py
        test_settings.py
```

The problem is that when I'm running tests from Pycharm directly from `test_settings.py` (by pressing on the green triangle) it works fine, however if I running them from command line using `python -m unittest` I obtain such error:

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_settings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Users\alexc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "D:\github\Queue_Managment\tests\test_settings.py", line 2, in <module>
    from application.settings import load_config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
```

I've tried to edit the path using `sys` and `os.path` but it doesn't help.

Comment: I guess you mean `python -m` instead of `pycharm -m`. Did you run this from the `Project` directory?

Comment: @MrBean Bremen edited, thanks. I tried from proj-directory using `python -m unittest discover tests` and from "tests"-directory using `python -m unittest`

Comment: Hm, if you run from the project directory `python -m unittest tests/test_settings.py`, it doesn't work? Or `python -m unittest discover tests/`.

Comment: @MrBean Bremen unfortunately, no. I've tried both.

Comment: I just tried it locally with a similar layout, and it worked... you are in Python 3, right?

Comment: @MrBean Bremen yep. 
`D:\github\Queue_Managment\env\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.1\plugins\python\helpers\pycharm\_jb_unittest_runner.py" --target test_settings.TestSettingsCases
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest test_settings.TestSettingsCases in D:\github\Queue_Managment\tests` and tried to use this one `python -m unittest test_settings.TestSettingsCases` from /tests

Comment: Well, if you use `python -m` it adds the current directory to the Python path, so it _should_ find `application` - I'm out of ideas. Maybe something in the test itself, e.g. in the imports, though I have no idea what - sorry...